# flake8 - E999 syntax error with python3 metaclass argument

Tags: python, metaclass, flake8

I am using vim for python development with flake8 as the linter. Below is the sample code containing metaclases. Flake8 is showing error ***E999 SyntaxError: invalid syntax (E)*** on the line `class Spam(metaclass=MyMeta)`. I am using python3 and this is the correct syntax for specifying custom metaclasses in python3.

```
class MyMeta(type):

    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, clsbody):
        upper_case = {}
        for k, v in clsbody.items():
            if not k.startswith('__'):
                upper_case[k.upper()] = v
        return super().__new__(cls, clsname, bases, upper_case)


class Spam(metaclass=MyMeta):
    foo = 'bar'
```

Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: What plugin you use? `Python-mode?`

Comment: No, actually i use a combination of Neomake, Deoplete and Deoplete-jedi and jedi-vim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you are editing Python3 code, and your flake8 is obviously checking the syntax for Python2.

Looking around the internet, the straightforward way to force flake8 to check for Python3 is to run it *from* Python3.

You are likely on Linux or other Unix (I took the hint from the VIM usage), so, if flake8 is installed system-wide, uninstall it, and install it in Python3 (in fedora and redhatish distros, it is `dnf uninstall python2-flake8` `dnf install python3-flake8`).

A more proper approach might be just set up a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) for your Python project, with the desired Python version, install flake8 inside this virtualenv, with `pip install flake8`, and *also*  start VIM from inside your virtualenv, so that any Python scripts or programs it runs are on the same environment, and even things like advanced auto-complete can check the libraries your project is actually using.

Comment: I am not sure why it bugged only for `metaclass` only, it was working fine for other python3 syntax.